# Python 3.6 on win 10 editdistance module can not be imported ( DLL load failed problem )

Tags: python

editdistance module of Hiroyuki Tanaka can not be imported on python 3.6 windows 10

python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 7, in 
import editdistance
File "C:....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\editdistance_*init*_.py", line 1, in

```
**from .bycython import eval**
```

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

What can be the problem is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing concerned people.

The problem was not specific about the editdistance module, it was about calling  c++ modules from python. I think that somehow redistributable VC++ files in my computer gets corrupted . So i have reloaded the file vc_redist.x64.exe from :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

And choosed the "repair" option.

After that everything looks ok.

Thanks